# Como usar um serviço do angular fora da estrutura do angular?

Tags: angularjs

No angular temos um serviço chamado `$http`. Eu sei que para chamá-lo basta passar como parâmetro de uma closure, que o angular faz a mágica:

```
angular.module('foo').controller(function ($http) { 
   /** ... **/ 
});
```

E se eu quiser usar o `$http` fora do `controller` ou `config`? Tem como?

Existe uma forma de usar um serviço do angular sem ser por injeção de dependências em parâmetros de funções?

Por exemplo:

```
var $http = ...; // pego a instância do serviço aqui...

$http.get('/pagina-do-site').then(function () {

})
```

Comment: Onde exatamente você deseja usar isso? Consegue citar um exemplo prático?

Comment: Quando fui fazer um plugin para o chrome, precisei fazer isso. Usar o HTTP "fora do Angular". Não quero depender do `$.ajax` do jQuery, mas eu realmente precisei usar "globalmente" o `$http`. Pode ser que eu tenha errado na minha estrutura, mas no "background.js" do Chrome não tinha porque ter um `app.module`. Eu realmente precisava apenas do `$http` (para não usar jQuery).

Comment: Eu, particularmente, desconheço um método de usar não só o $http, como qualquer outro serviço do Angular, fora de seu escopo, devido as "dependências" estruturais e de eventos que ele tem.

Comment: Na verdade eu consegui fazer isso usando o recurso do próprio angular. Eu só queria saber se tinha um jeito melhor. Eu consegui assim `var $http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http");`

Comment: @CelsomTrindade nesse caso específico, veja: http://pastebin.com/wGCAucTs

Comment: Humm.. Interessante!!! Eu uso esse recurso atualmente, mas de modo inverso. Eu faço lazyload de algum módulo que só é necessário em determinada view e depois faço a injeção dele DENTRO do angular. Mas bom saber que da para fazer para fora dele também!

Comment: Foi por isso que eu negativei a resposta abaixo. Achei muito estranho a forma que foi feita.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46344/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-celsomtrindade).

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você queira usar o `$http` fora da estrutura interna do angular, você usar o método `angular.injector`:

```
var $http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http");
```

Answer (score -1):

Existe um hack para isso:

```
angular.module('your-module').run(['$http',function($http){
    window.$http = $http;
}];
```

Assim voce pode usar o $http em qualquer lugar chamando window.$http desde que a chamada seja feita depois da inicialização do angular.

Comment: Péssima ideia. Se eu precisar isso em um contexto que não for o global, como seria feito? Além do que o Angular parece oferecer uma solução mais elegante para isso.

Comment: Na verdade Guilherme, o serviço $http pode ser usado em qualquer área do AngularJs, não é como o $scope que possui limitações. Ex.: `factory('minhaFactory', function($scope) {});` Isso não é possível. Então a sua solução é meio 'redundante' visto que continua dentro do escopo do AngularJs.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters A ideia é poder usar fora do contexto do angular em algum tipo de migração para o angular onde alguma área que ainda não foi migrada precisa acessar os serviços feitos no angular por algum motivo.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade A ideia não é abandonar o angular e sim disponibilizar um serviço que só está disponível através de injeção de dependencia dentro do angular para áreas "legadas" de uma aplicação que estão fora do angular.